# If $V$ is finite-dimensional with $J : V \to V$ such that $J^2 = -id$, then $V$ has even dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, almost-complex

Let $V$ be a $\Bbb R$-vector space, with $J$ being an endomorphism $J: V \to V$ with $J^2=-id$ (identity).

I already had to show that $V$ became a $\Bbb C$-vector space with the scalar multiplication: $$(a+bi)\cdot v=av+bJ(v).$$

Now $V$ is set to be finite-dimensional. The problem is the following:

**Show that $\operatorname{dim}_{\Bbb R} V$ is even.**

Any ideas on how to show this? (I've seen the post [If $V$ is a vector space, then, proving that...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350519/if-v-is-a-vector-space-then-proving-that) which has the same problem but I don't really get the solution that is offered there, they write $J$ as a matrix, so far so good, but from there I don't get it.)

Comment: take determinant of the equation $J^2 = -Id$.

Comment: but what is the connection between determinant and dimension?

Comment: what is $\det (-Id)$?

Comment: "Now $V$ is set to be finite." I believe you mean finite-dimensional.

Comment: $\det (-Id)$ is $(-1)^{dimV}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $V$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}V$ is an integer, so $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}V = 2\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}V$ is even.

By the way, $J$ is sometimes called a [linear complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure).

Answer (score 5):

Use this

$$\det(-id)=(-1)^{\dim V}=\det(J^2)=(\det(J))^2\ge0$$

**Alternative** Other way to prove the result is to consider the polynomial $P=x^2+1$ which annihilate $J$ so the only complex eigenalues of $J$ are $\pm i$ and since $J$ is real then the characteristic polynomial has real coefficients and $P$ divides it so

$$\chi_J(x)=(x^2+1)^p$$
and then $\dim V=2p$.